# Joining tables with DataTable column header name

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datatable

I'm using SQL to SELECT from multiple tables and I join them into 1 DataTable. The code looks something like:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("(SELECT Table1, Col2, Col3 FROM Table1DB" + "UNION SELECT Table2, Col2, Col3 FROM Table2DB", connection);


        SqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        myAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

Now everything works fine, but when I look at the content of my dt, I notice that the column headers are as follows: Table1, Col2, Col3. The actual values of Table2 that were selected are right, but I'm just wondering why the headers only use the names from the first SELECT? And is there any way to change it?

It's not a big deal but it feels silly doing something like this to select the first column of every row:

```
dt2.Rows[count]["Table1"].ToString());
```

where count is the row I'm on. I feel like it would look better if there was a more universal column name instead of the primary key for the first SELECT?

Comment: When you UNION (btw, UNION is different from JOIN) two tables there is only one column header containing names, because you essentially combine both of them into one. This is absolutely logical. If you want, you can apply alias to the column names so in final table you will get the names you want.

Comment: Gotcha thanks. How do I apply a alias?

Comment: You are welcome. For example, SELECT Table1 as MyNewTable1, Col2 As NewCol2, and so on.